# Parent Div Background not filling child

Tags: html, css

How come the image in the background of parent div is not filling the child divs?

Fiddle with the problem is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/45jQm/

```
.sub
{
    border: 1px dashed #f00;
    padding: 5px;
    background:url('http://jpdevtest.com/vandermill/images/home-page-background.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}

.subtext
{
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px dashed #0f0;
}

.homeimage
{
    float: right;
    width: 300px;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px dashed #0f0;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.subtext` and `.homeimage` are floated and no longer in the normal flow causing their container to ignore them instead of growing with them.

You can add `overflow: auto;` to create a new [block-formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting) within `.sub`

```
.sub {
border: 1px dashed #f00;
padding: 5px;
background:url('http://jpdevtest.com/vandermill/images/home-page-background.jpg') no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/45jQm/1/

Comment: And to suppliment this answer, here is an article that may help you understand the underlying issue: http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html

Answer (score 1):

You have to clear you floats. Two options:

#### 1. Adding element with `clear: both`:

```
<div class="clr"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/45jQm/2/

#### 2. More semantic, using `clearfix` class on the parent container:

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}
/* For IE 6/7 */
.clearfix {
    zoom: 1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/45jQm/3/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your floats must be cleared for the parent element to fully contain the floated child elements.  Try adding `overflow:hidden` to your `.sub` rules.

Answer (score 0):

Add overflow:hidden on your parent div

```
.sub
{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

You float the inner divs, so they are pulled out of the render context of the outer div. You could also:
- float the outer div
- add an element at the bottom of the outer div with `style='clear:both;display:block'`

Answer (score 0):

It's because `.sub` childs are all **floated**. So you need **clearfix**.

One solution is add `overflow` to your `.sub` element with a value other than `visible`:

```
.sub { overflow: hidden; }
```

- [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/45jQm/4/)

---

Another solution is adding an element with `clear: both;` style after all childs:

```
<div class="sub">
    <div class="subtext"></div>
    <div class="homeimage"></div>

    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

- [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/45jQm/5/)